# MuleDevKit - Build a Transformer and access it in the palette

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'am trying to build a custom transformer with Muledevkit. I am successful in building one and I can install it in my studio. But I couldn't figure out a way how to allow the end-user to set a property (like how its shown in custom-transformer under the 'Transformer Settings' -> 'Property') to access inside my Transformer class.

Regards,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a feature not covered by the DevKit transformers.

Because DevKit transformers can be implicitly called (Mule out of the box mechanism to resolve transformers), there are some constrains we have to follow.

The only work around I can think of is to create a processor that does the transformation for you.

I'll add this as a feature request on our backlog.

HTH